# Where to Find Internal ID for Line Items in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

[Need Internal Id for Description Line Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwWNu.jpg)

Comment: I guess it is a SO form. Did you try using `description` ? Show your code so we can help you out.

Comment: thank you Rockstar its working using descrition...

Answer (score 4):

You may check it by either thru (Should be logged-in to the account):


SuiteScript Record Browser:

- [Production](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/script/record/account.html)
- [Sandbox](https://system.sandbox.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/script/record/account.html)

[image]



Or adding "&xml=T" to the url of the current transaction page.

Example: "https://system.sandbox.netsuite.com/app/accounting/transactions/salesord.nl?id=8132&whence=&xml=T"

[image]